# Swift / MongoDB Server - The data couldn't be read because it isnt in the correct format.

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mongodb

I am developing a simple application with a login screen. In the code for my view controller (LoginViewController) I created the following function, which should allow a user to sign up. However, when I test the application, the console tells me "The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format."

```
@IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {
    let newUser = PFUser()

    newUser.username = usernameField.text as String!
    newUser.password = passwordField.text as String!
    newUser.signUpInBackground { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
        if success {
            print("Created User")
        } else {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that im running into a type error of some kind? Does the text field expect a data type other than a string? Any idea as to why this is happening? Any known solutions?

Comment: Can you print the newUser.username & newUser.password before signUp ? What values does it have ?

Answer (score 0):

These two lines are kind of weird:

```
newUser.username = usernameField.text as String!
newUser.password = passwordField.text as String!
```

Are the `username` and `password` variables on PFUser implicitly Unwrapped optionals? Even then, we don't usually write code like this in Swift. We'd probably write something along the lines of:

```
    @IBAction func onSignUp(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let usernameText = usernameField.text, let passwordText = passwordField.text else {return}
        let newUser = PFUser()
        newUser.username = usernameText
        newUser.password = passwordText
        newUser.signUpInBackground { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
            if success {
                print("Created User")
            } else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Try that